# Using Jest and Enzyme, how do I test a function passed in through props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Using Jest and Enzyme, how can I test if this.props.functionToTest was run?

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
   static propTypes = {
     functionToTest: PropTypes.func
   }
   componentDidMount() {
     this.props.functionToTest()
   }
}
```

In Jest, I've tried creating mockProps and passing them in when mounting the component.

```
let props = {
  functionToTest = jest.fn(() => {});
}
beforeEach(() => {
  const wrapper = mount(<TestComponent {...props} />
}
```

A console.log in the componentDidMount function shows functionToTest as undefined.  Obviously passing in the props during mount isn't working.

Question 1:  How can I pass in mock props that will show in the componentDidMount function?

Question 2:  Once that function is available, how do I gain access to the function so I can use spyOn or something similar to test if the function was run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that TestComponent was only being exported within the Redux wrapper.  Adding an export at the class level and destructuring it in the Jest test import, along with the solution Henrick posted above fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know your exact setup, but this is how I would do that:

- Mock the function with `jest.fn()` like you did
- Pass mock to the component being mounted (like apparently you did)
- Check whether it was run with `expect(...).toBeCalled()` or `.toHaveBeenCalled()` (varies between different Jest versions)

.

```
let props = {
  functionToTest: jest.fn() // You don't need to define the implementation if it's empty
};

beforeEach(() => {
  const wrapper = mount(<TestComponent {...props} />
}

// In the test code:
it('does something', () => {
    expect(props.functionToTest).toBeCalled();
    // OR... depending on your version of Jest
    expect(props.functionToTest).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: The props in the console.log in componentDidMount is still showing each prop as undefined.  Could how I import the TestComponent into the Jest test have anything to do with it?
I'm simply importing it using
   
   import TestComponent from "../TestComponent"

Comment: if there are no mocks for that component (which could either be in the test file or set up inside a `__mocks__` folder nearby), then that would only depend on what's being exported from the component. If you're able to mount it, I wouldn't guess there's a problem there, but maybe worth trying to access anything else on it that proves it's the correct component you got.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of that might affect this is that I'm using Redux.  

So the bottom of the TestComponent is
export default connect(
mapStateToProps,
mapDispatchToProps,
}(TestComponent)

I didn't think that would have any effect on this because functionToTest is being passed in through the parent component, not redux.

Comment: That does change things. Your intended component becomes a child in the wrapper. I would encourage you to detach components and use the unwrapped version instead for unit testing as it would make your life much easier. If however you want or need to settle for less readable code, then grab the inner component from `wrapper.childAt(0)`.
But you only need to go through that hassle if you need to do something else with the component instance in the test. If you're merely trying to test whether `functionToTest` has been called, the answer above should be enough and make for readable code.